# Making a composite std::function

Tags: c++, tr1

I have created this functor, `Functions`, which is meant to store a number of `std::functions`, and call them, sequentially, as if it was a `std::function` itself:

```
typedef std::function <void (int)> FuncType;

struct Functions
{
    vector<FuncType> m;

    void operator+= (FuncType f) { 
        m.push_back(f);
    }
    void operator() (int param ){  // same prototype as FuncType
        vector<FuncType>::iterator it;
        for(it=m.begin(); it!=m.end(); ++it) {
            (*it)(param);
        }
    }
};
```

It is very useful in that it can be stored in a `FuncType`:

```
int main()
{
    Functions f;
    f += foo;
    f += bar;

    FuncType ptr(f);

    ptr(10);  // calls foo(10), then bar(10)
}
```

it works fine, but I want to be able to make this a templated functor. But I cannot think of a way to make the `operator()` follow the prototype of the functions:

```
template <typename FuncType>    // for any Function type
struct Functions
{
    vector<FuncType> m;

    void operator+= (FuncType f) { 
        m.push_back(f);
    }

    void operator() (...) {  // how do I get the same prototype as FuncType?
        vector<FuncType>::iterator it;
        for(it=m.begin(); it!=m.end(); ++it) {
            (*it)(...);
        }
    }
};
```

Ideally, I'd like to also  have a *helper function*, which instantiates the functor (provided of course, that all functions have the same prototype), like so:

```
template <typename T>
Functions<T> make_functions( T funcA, T funcB ) {
    Functions<T> f;
    f += funcA;
    f += funcB;
    return f;
}
```

but I am not sure that the compiler can deduce that `T` is a std::function<> of some sort.

I am working with `std::tr1`

Comment: Note that the stuff in `std::tr1` is now mostly (all?) part of the C++11 standard, which your compiler should support by now. You don't need to address the namespace, as it is effectively obsolete - everything is already in `std`.

Comment: @MoreAxes  unfortunately, `std::tr1` is the common denominator of the compilers I use. VS2010 is one of them, and it does not support variadic templates

Answer (score 5):

```
template<typename Sig> struct Functions;
template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct Functions<R(Args...)>{
  typedef std::function<R(Args...)> FuncType;
  std::vector<FuncType> fs;
  void operator+=(FuncType f){fs.emplace_back(std::move(f));}
  template<typename...Us>
  void operator()(Us&&...us){
    for(auto&&f:fs)
      f(us...);
  }
};
int main(){
  Functions<void(int)> funcs;
  funcs += [](int x){ std::cout<<x<<"\n";};
  funcs(7);
}
```

Real perfect forwarding and collecting return values left as exercise.

Comment: I like this template signature better than CantChooseUsernames'

Comment: Nice. Not part of the question, but collecting return values and/or choosing what to return is non-trivial, not even well defined. I think this is what [combiners](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/signals/s06.html#idp204727928) do in [boost::signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/signals.html).

Comment: @iavr I did not say it was an **easy** exercise!  Real perfect forwarding is an easier, but a touch messier, exercise.  Bunch of work to block rvalue references (cannot call more than one) or duplicate parameters for each call (but the last) in that case, move only on last call while handling empty collection, etc -- messy work.  One simple way to deal with `R` is if non-void, return `std::vector<R>` from `()`.

Answer (score 3):

What about something like this? EDIT: as pointed out, I missed the `make_function` and the opportunity to perfectly forward the arguments with `std::forward`. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f597aacd3b7ce404

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


template<typename T, typename... Args>
class Functions
{
    private:
        std::vector<std::function<T(Args...)>> vec;

    public:
        void operator += (std::function<T(Args...)> f)
        {
            vec.push_back(f);
        }

        void operator()(Args... args)
        {
            for (auto &f : vec)
            {
                f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            }
        }
};

int main()
{
    Functions<void> funcs;
    funcs += []{std::cout<<"Foo\n";};
    funcs += []{std::cout<<"Bar\n";};

    funcs();
    std::cout<<"\n";

    Functions<void, int> funcs2;
    funcs2 += [](int a){std::cout<<"Foo"<<a<<"\n";};
    funcs2 += [](int b){std::cout<<"Bar"<<b<<"\n";};

    funcs2(2);
}
```

Comment: You missed the `make_functions` http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f597aacd3b7ce404

Comment: Good call on the `std::forward` too! I will just add your comment to the post if you don't mind.

Comment: Feel free to integrate some or all of it into the answer

Comment: FYI, I recommmend forwarding the function as well in the `+=`

Comment: Forward use invalid: you cannot move twice and expect things to make sense, and forward is conditional move.